# How can I add some image, controlled with back Smart Edit, on Spartacus storefront 3.0

Tags: templates, spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to add an outlet with an image to the Login layout. So far is working but I want the image to be controlled from the back with different sizes depending on viewport.

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="LoginPageTemplate" cxOutletPos="before" let-model>
  <p>here goes an image</p>
</ng-template>
```

How can I add a media there??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using outlets, I'd suggest adding yet another CMS component (banner component) in the CMS in the top of your `LoginPageTemplate`.

If you decide to add banner component in a separate slot, then you may need to tweak your Spartacus `LayoutConfig` for the `LoginPageTemplate` to display your new slot (see docs https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/page-layout/)

...and, if needed, fix CSS styling (see docs https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/).